# How does Figma handle login through Google authentication api?

Tags: javascript, authentication, jwt, google-oauth, figma

I am studying about authentication handling different approaches. One of website that I've checked,
is Figma.

When user logged in by google service provider,as i figured out, a fuid generates, and it is defined as a query params in URL.
Does Figma check user authentication by this variable? and if yes, why when i remove this variable from URL and also, from web browser storages, still we can see it in URL and user is still authenticated??
Thanks for help me.